# Access WCF from Jquery using JSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, wcf

Hi I'm trying to access a WCF service which returns a JSON Array using JQuery but its not working. But when I use a php service which is in internet it works.
please tell me where i'm going wrong?

My c# class

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Employee[] getData();
}


[DataContract]
public class Employee
{ 
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The response i get when i load it in browser

```
[{"id":"1","name":"test"},{"id":"2","name":"test"}]
```

the URL for php web service
http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php

my html code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:51220/Service1.svc/getdata",
      success: function(result){
        alert(result);
      },
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
    });
</script>
```

when i use this i get the error 0 but when i use the php service i get the array.

Comment: Why jsonp in local host ? Also can you show your endpoints in your config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:51220/Service1.svc/getdata",
                processData: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown);
                }
            })
```